# Epoch time increasing when running Pytorch on AML docker

Tags: docker, machine-learning, pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service

The epoch time keeps increasing when running Pytorch training on AML and a custom docker image.
When the same code is running locally the epoch time is constant (the difference here is that there is no docker image involved and the training dataset exists locally, so not a mounted blob storage by AML and the machine is different)

Any suggestions on how I can figure out what's happening?
For example how can I log useful memory consumption? GPU, Pytorch, disk access, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a fully scripted way, I usually do this kind of debugging by running my training in `tmux` session, with an active `htop` in the second terminal, and in your case an `nvidia-smi -l 1` in a third one.

Are you mounting the blob-store or downloading the data to the compute cluster?